# What are the impacts that drive how fast the binary version "catches up" with the source version for r packages?

Tags: r, package

If one loads r packages one can install from source or the binary version. 
The user is informed that a binary version exists but the "source version" is newer.

[image]

I am not sure, if this is the right place to ask, but i would be interested:

**Question:**

What are the impacts that drive how fast the binary version "catches up" with the source version?

**What i tried (to understand):**

If i download the source version and compile it on my system, that could be the binary version (for my system).
So it could just be a matter of time that someone compiled the source version for the system i am using (and it would be available as a binary download for me).

And if these assumptions are correct i could contribute my compiled version, so that the binary version is available faster to others or is there more testing involved.

Comment: These are good questions, they might get answered faster on the `r-package-devel@r-project.org` mailing list. I think the delay is entirely on the building end. In my experience Windows builds are usually quick, most of the delay is on the MacOS end. I don't know that individual contributions would help ... can't find any further useful information at http://mac.r-project.org/ , https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ ...